# Problem after interrupted installation of Adobe Flash

Tags: package-management, flash

I am using Ubuntu. Yesterday I have installed Adobe Flash plugin to my laptop. The installation was *interrupted*,and it didn't complete. However, the software shows in the installed software menu. Today I have tried to install another program, but the attempt failed, with error message 'your last installation was incomplete, fix that first'. The problem is that I can't remove Adobe Flash from the laptop,and can't install anything else. Kindly help me.

Comment: It is quite difficult to understand your question. Are you asking how to remove adobe flash? If so, you can edit your question title and body to clarify.

Comment: Sorry for having edited your question that much, but it was very unclear for some. I hope now you will be more likely to get helpful answers. Cheers!

Comment: Just a note: this is related (same question, actually): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34768/cant-install-software-in-ubuntu-says-last-download-was-incomplete-and-must-be

Answer (score 2):

You will need to completely remove Adobe Flash Player Plugin and re-install using the commands below:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. $ `sudo apt-get remove --purge adobe-flashplugin flashplugin* nspluginwrapper`
3. $ `sudo apt-get install --reinstall adobe-flashplugin`

Comment: E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem. -hai this was the reply.how i fix it..

Comment: @bobprasnt run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` to continue the installation of the package, after its done it should be correctly installed.