# Distribution upgrade frozen at "flashplugin-installer: downloading http..."

Tags: networking, upgrade, flash, freeze

I have just started to upgrade from ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04, which I was at the library for... And when it got to 10mins remaining on "installing the upgrades" and the library closed, and now the upgrade has froze and the terminal (had open b4 disconnecting net) says: "flashplugin-installer: downloading http..."

I am currently at my granddad's place who has  wireless internet; however I can't connect to it due to me typing the incorrect password. And when I plug it into the cable it says it connects but firefox can't acess the internet.

After searching on my phone, I think I have some ideas on how to fix this issue, but don't know how to do them. If u can help with any of them it will b very helpful:

1. Connect to the internet and allow it to download. The only problem is that the cable won't connect and wireless password is incorrect, and I don't know how to change the wireless password on the system, though when I go into Network connections, nothing shows  up under any of the connection tabs, although the wireless still shows in the dropdown menu on the top bar. If you know how to change the password in wireless password in the ternimal it will help.
2. Another thing I've found is that with some other people using terminal to cancel the particular thig that froze it made it start working agin, so if anyone knows the command to cancel the flashplugin-installer that might also help.
3. Really don't want to risk it, but if it's at this point and I shutdown, will it break my OS, or will it be OK? (I will only do it if it is safe and as a last resort).

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and used "pstree -p" to find the hanging process for solution Nr. 2.

The relevant part was:

```
    +-gksu(1918)---sudo(2396)---precise(2397)---precise(2801)
    ¦                                         +-precise(2802)---dpkg(8231)---update-notifier(19401)---package-data-do(19403)
    ¦                                         ¦               +-{precise}(2804)
    ¦                                         +-sh(2772)---sleep(31266)
    ¦                                         +-{precise}(2399)
    ¦                                         +-{precise}(2400)
    ¦                                         +-{precise}(2803)
```

Killing 19403 ("package-data-do") made the process move forward again.

Comment: Just as a note. This still works for halting installations of 13.10.

Comment: Great! I spent almost an hour looking at the terminal screen like an idiot, saying "come on..."

Answer (score 1):

`flashplugin-installer` is a program to install flash-plugin.
You can install it by the terminal, but "Adobe is very poor to buy a good server" , the download speed of `flashplugin-installer` is about 5KB/s, so if you install flash on this way, you must wait for a long time...

I don't have an answer for your first point.

For your second question, take a look at [Problem after interrupted installation of Adobe Flash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115192/problem-after-interrupted-installation-of-adobe-flash)

About point three, I think it's ok for your mac, but your ubuntu will die...