# How to resume interrupted installation in Synaptic Manager?

Tags: installation, synaptic

I use Lubuntu 12.04 and have tried to install lubuntu-restricted-extras in Synaptic.

It seemed stuck at one point: when asked to accept some Microsoft EULA for fonts (I guess), I hit Enter and it seemed to me that I could not do anything but try to shut down synaptic, which I could not do and finally logged out.

Maybe I should not have done that but that is what I did.

After logging in and then after reboot, no installation would  start, as if Synaptic was still working.

The problem seems to be with the installation of lubuntu-restricted-extras being incomplete.

What is it to be done?

When I type

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I get:

```
dpkg: error: dpkg status database is locked by another process
```

I found [here](http://ariesyoussefian.com/2011/10/17/fix-dpkg-status-database-locked-process-ubuntu/) that I could type

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

before

```
 sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then update (works ok) and upgrade, at which point I get

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  accountsservice apparmor apport apport-gtk apt apt-transport-https apt-utils
  aptdaemon aptdaemon-data audacious-plugins audacious-plugins-data base-files
  bind9-host blueman cron cups cups-client cups-common cups-driver-gutenprint
  cups-filters cups-ppdc dconf-gsettings-backend dconf-service
  desktop-file-utils dmsetup dnsutils evince evince-common firefox-locale-en
  fonts-liberation foomatic-filters ghostscript ghostscript-cups ghostscript-x
  gir1.2-gtk-3.0 gir1.2-pango-1.0 glib-networking glib-networking-common
  glib-networking-services gnome-icon-theme gnome-icon-theme-full grub-common
  grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common gstreamer0.10-plugins-base hdparm
  initscripts isc-dhcp-client isc-dhcp-common jockey-common jockey-gtk
  krb5-locales libaccountsservice0 libapt-inst1.4 libapt-pkg4.12 libasound2
  libbind9-80 libcairo-gobject2 libcairo2 libcups2 libcupscgi1 libcupsfilters1
  libcupsimage2 libcupsmime1 libcupsppdc1 libdbusmenu-glib4 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4
  libdconf0 libdevmapper-event1.02.1 libdevmapper1.02.1 libdns81 libevince3-3
  libexif12 libexpat1 libfm-data libfm-gtk-data libfm-gtk1 libfm1 libgail-3-0
  libgcrypt11 libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-glx libglade2-0 libglapi-mesa
  libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin libglib2.0-data libglu1-mesa libgnutls26
  libgphoto2-2 libgphoto2-port0 libgrip0 libgs9 libgs9-common libgssapi-krb5-2
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common
  libgudev-1.0-0 libgutenprint2 libisc83 libisccc80 libisccfg82
  libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0 libjpeg-turbo8 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3
  libkrb5support0 liblaunchpad-integration-3.0-1
  liblaunchpad-integration-common liblaunchpad-integration1 libldap-2.4-2
  liblightdm-gobject-1-0 liblvm2app2.2 liblwres80 libmtp-common libmtp9
  libnautilus-extension1a libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2
  libpango1.0-0 libperl5.14 libpolkit-agent-1-0 libpolkit-backend-1-0
  libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libpulse-mainloop-glib0 libpulse0 libpurple0
  libpython2.7 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsmbclient libsqlite3-0
  libssl1.0.0 libtasn1-3 libtiff4 libudev0 libutouch-geis1 libv4l-0
  libv4lconvert0 libwbclient0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-1.0-common
  libxatracker1 libxkbfile1 libxml2 libxslt1.1 lightdm lxkeymap nautilus-data
  network-manager ntp ntpdate openssl perl perl-base perl-modules pidgin
  pidgin-data policykit-1 printer-driver-gutenprint psmisc python-apport
  python-aptdaemon python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets python-cupshelpers python-gi
  python-gobject python-libxml2 python-problem-report
  python-software-properties python2.7 python2.7-minimal resolvconf
  shared-mime-info simple-scan software-properties-common
  software-properties-gtk ssl-cert sudo system-config-printer-common
  system-config-printer-gnome sysv-rc sysvinit-utils ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  udev udisks update-manager update-manager-core update-notifier
  update-notifier-common upstart vim-common vim-tiny xkb-data xserver-common
  xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
  xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-vmware
205 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Synaptic can be opened, which did not happened before. But when I try to install lubuntu-restricted-extras in synaptic I get this:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock the download directory
```

Comment: Did you try using the tab key to highlight the **Accept** button when you asked to accept the EULA?

Comment: no, i just hit enter... so it seemed stuck to me and I interrupted the installation by logging out!...

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/349469/comments/8 that seems to have helped

Comment: @cipricus - You can post the above linked solution here and accept your own answer , that would help other users with same problem, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is close to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/115192/47206) and to others that now I don't seem able to find  here. I will re-edit when I 'll find them.

It is **[a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debconf/+bug/349469/comments/8)** it looks like, and the solution consists in typing

```
sudo rm -rf /var/cache/debconf/*
sudo apt-get install -f
```

which seems to resume the  broken installation. I had some errors but then I was able to make installations.

The full upgrade involved some errors that only a partial upgrade is possible, but the interrupted installation seems to have been resolved during this upgrade (including that Microsoft EULA that was again presented to me -- see comments to the question) and after that, and a reboot, things look fine.